# Do not run testng test method if data provided to test contains some value

Tags: testng

I want to make `@Test(enable=false)` if data provider gives some exception data to test method. for example.
my test method signature is like this.

```
    @Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider" , enabled='true') 
    public void test(ITestContext itc, String record) throws Throwable
```

so if `record.contains("Upload")` then do `enabled='false'`. 
I don't want to embed that logic inside test method. I want to use annotation transformation. this is the signature of the transform method

```
 public void transform(ITest annotation, Class testClass, 
                        Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod)
```

I don't have access to record object [data provider] in transform method.can I inject that data into transform method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the parameter value in `IAnnotationTransformer` is not possible. 
Instead, we can extend the `TestListenerAdapter` and override the `onTestStart()` method to get the parameters using which the test was invoked. After comparing the parameter, we can issue a `SkipException` to skip running the test.

```
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

public class CustomListen4 extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // Get the parameter 2nd parameter used to invoke the test method
        String record = (String) result.getParameters()[1];
        // If record contains upload skip the test
        if (record.contains("upload")) {
            throw new SkipException("Test skipped because of bad parameter - " + record);
        }
        super.onTestStart(result);
    }
}
```

Tested using **TestNG 6.14.3**

```
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClass1 {

    @DataProvider
    public Object[] myDataprovider() {
        return new Object[] { "upload", "download" };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "myDataprovider")
    public void test(ITestContext itc, String record) {
        System.out.println("test execution with parameter - " + record);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
test execution with parameter - download
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 1.321 sec - in TestSuite
```

As you can see that the test with parameter "upload" is not executed and the skip count is 1.